# Initialize dynamic array

Tags: c++, matrix

I created a dynamic array in this way:

```
arr = new int*[m];
for(size_t i=0;i<m;++i){
    arr[i]=new int[n];
}
```

The values of `m` and `n` is 3, I got a matrix which each cell contain 2 or 1 the matrix look like this.

```
{{2,1,2,1},
{1,2,2,2},
{1,1,1,1},
{2,1,1,2}}
```

I create the array as part of class at the cpp file, the is any option I can initialize the array without using a parameter which contain the matrix and then using a loop that goes over each `[i][j]` of the matrix and copy it to the dynamic array.
Moreover the solution of write 16 code lines are not good because the array can be bigger than the one I gave upon. The matrix doesn't an input from the user it the default array. 
So there any solution for my initialize the array without using loops and without using another parameter that contain the matrix?

Comment: Note that you created a _dynamic array of dynamic arrays of ints_. Which is probably the simplest way to do things, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Suggest using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. You can initialize it to contain any number of elements having a specific value at once using one of the constructor forms, and you also free yourself from managing the array's memory yourself.

Comment: @cdhowie: A vector of vectors is a bad idea if locality of data is important (which it almost certainly is for a matrix.)  You're better of calculating indices into one big vector here.

Comment: @EdS. Or that -- using a matrix class to hide that detail would be good, IMO. At least a vector of vectors is better than an array of arrays. One step better.

Comment: @cdhowie: In terms of maintainability and simplicity, yes, I agree, but often times that's not the only driving factor.  I agree that the element access details should be hidden when creating anything but a small, throwaway application.

Comment: Agreeing with Ed S. here.  If you need your data to be all in one big blob (which allows you to do bulk assignment operations like memset), then a single vector that you can then use modulus arithmetic to simulate "rows" is best  

`Row [2] Column [3] is arr[(2 * (rowSize)) + 3]`

Comment: @cdhowie: unfortunately I not allowed to use vector for this assigment so I must use dynamic array, and that why I asked the question above.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code, with `m` and `n` being 3:

```
arr = new int*[m];
for(size_t i=0; i < m; ++i) {
    arr[i]=new int[n];
}
```

Then you'll end up with a matrix which is filled with unintialized values, you can't asume the value you are going to have in each cell.
Provided you change your code to:

```
arr = new int*[m];
for(size_t i=0; i < m; ++i) {
    arr[i]=new int[n];
    memset( arr[ i ], 0, sizeof( int ) * n ); 
}
```

Then, the matrix will be a 3x3 one:

```
{ { 0, 0, 0 }
  { 0, 0, 0 }
  { 0, 0, 0 } }
```

Okay, now, how can you avoid the use of for loop while initializing? We can use the same trick as above, with `memset()`, and allocate the array in one big piece.

```
struct Array {
    int * v;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};

Array * createArray(int rows, int cols)
{
    const int Length = rows * cols;
    Array * toret = new Array;

    toret.v = new int[ Length ];
    memset( toret, 0, Length );
    toret.rows = rows;
    toret.cols = cols;

    return toret;
}

int getCell(const Array * a, int row, int col)
{
    return a->v[ ( row * a->cols ) + col ];
}
```

I am not sure whether you are actually using C or C++. In case of using C++, it would be more appropriate to create a class instead of a struct with independent functions.

```
class Array {
public:
    Array(int rs, int cs)
         :rows( rs ), cols( cs )
    {
        const int Length = rows * cols;

        v = new int[ Length ];
        memset( v, 0, Length );
    }

    ~Array()
    {
       delete[] v;
    }

    int &cell(int row, int col)
    {
        return v[ ( row * cols ) + col ];
    }

private:
    int * v;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using C++ and therefore I use also class but at the code you wrote, you initialize all the cells at the array to zero. I got a specific 2 dimentional array of values of 1 and 2 and I need to place it as it is shown at the matrix above. Moreover I'm not allowed to use vectors, and I hven't studied how to use memset so there any other options?

Comment: Under that circumstance, the only way is to use memcpy(addr1, addr2, size), which copies in addr1 the contents (up to size) of addr2. Check it out: http://ideone.com/VC6prB

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you may have:

```
int **arr = new int*[4];
arr[0] = new int[4]{2,1,2,1};
arr[1] = new int[4]{1,2,2,2};
arr[2] = new int[4]{1,1,1,1};
arr[3] = new int[4]{2,1,1,2};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/4KgP34)

But I strongly suggest `std::array` ([Live example](https://ideone.com/shLISI)) or `std::vector`